# Should "Is this wall load bearing" questions be considered off topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd say a few times a month we get a question about a particular wall being load bearing, and from what I have seen, the questions never get a good answer other than "probably or probably not".  The one picture usually provided is never enough to make a determination, and when additional pictures are added, they are still not enough to make a definitive call over the internet.

In the rare case that the wall is clearly not load bearing, the question helps exactly one person.  Everyone else's wall will be slightly different.  There's also the fact that almost all of these wall removing situations are going to require a permit and an expert evaluation *anyway*, so it even reduces the usefulness of the answer to that one person.  Then there's the question of giving the wrong answer.

I wanted to see what others thought.  Maybe there's something that makes these questions useful that I'm not seeing.

Comment: It's funny that this goes to meta with an upvote of 5 but there are literally 1000s of duplicate electrical questions.   There are actually so many duplicates that the mods would have a hard time figuring out which old question to make a new one a duplicate of.   As a user and someone who answers questions (and I can answer electrical but figure why when there are 20 others that can), I look at the homepage and my eyes glaze over with the same electrical questions.   Someone actually doing something with their home is at least different and interesting - and you can learn building techniques.

Comment: @DMoore, My concern wasn't that they were duplicates, but that there is very rarely enough information to make the call over the internet.  We can give hints like "look for joists that are parallel to the wall", but that little bit of info can be dangerous if they don't _really_ understand what they are looking for.  Tripping a breaker because you connected the wrong wires is better than a roof collapse, but I guess plumbing and electrical questions also have a risk of getting someone into trouble.

Answer (score 9):

You can vote to close them as a duplicate of this [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4/2196). Disclaimer, I've got the accepted answer on that one.

Or if they are different than that question, but not enough detail is available to make a proper judgement, then you can vote to close with "needs more clarity".